# flutter_background_service not receiving updates

Tags: flutter, dart, background-process, dart-isolates, awesome-notifications

I'm using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications/example) and [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example) in conjunction to update some app state when receiving data notifications from FirebaseMessaging. As noted in the awesome_notifications, the background message handler must be a top-level function, so I am using flutter_background_service to pass data to the main isolate and update app state.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeBackgroundService();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_backgroundMessageHandler);
  _initLocalNotifications();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I'm initializing the background service similarly to the example in flutter_background_service:

```
Future<void> initializeBackgroundService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );
  await service.startService();
}
```

and invoking update in the _backgroundMessageHandler when a notification is received:

```
Future<void> _backgroundMessageHandler(
  RemoteMessage message,
) async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  ...

  service.invoke('update', {
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': 'val2',
  });
}
```

And in the StatefulWidget for my app in the main isolate, I'm listening on the update call to receive the data:

```
void listenForNotificationData() {
  final backgroundService = FlutterBackgroundService();
  backgroundService.on('update').listen((event) async {
    print('received data message in feed: $event');
  }, onError: (e, s) {
    print('error listening for updates: $e, $s');
  }, onDone: () {
    print('background listen closed');
  });
}
```

It's never invoking the listen callback on the 'update' event. I can confirm it's calling the invoke('update') portion and calling on('update').listen, but never receiving the update. It also doesn't seem to be erroring out. Am I missing a step somewhere here?

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue on flutter background service. I solved it by removing the async keyword from the callback and creating a separate async function to perform the callback operations.

```js
void listenForNotificationData() {
  final backgroundService = FlutterBackgroundService();
  backgroundService.on('update').listen((event) {
    print('received data message in feed: $event');
  }, onError: (e, s) {
    print('error listening for updates: $e, $s');
  }, onDone: () {
    print('background listen closed');
  });
}

void action(Map? event) async {
print('received data message in feed: $event');
}
```

Hope it helps, forgive me if there are syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a new class.

```
class ProjectBackgroundService{}
```

Now let's define the functions that you will use in this class.

The first of these will be the **readyForShared()** function. This function allows us to define and read local variables.

```
`Future<void> readyForShared() async {
   var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   counterValue = sharedPreferences.getString("yourVariable") ??"0";
 }`
```

Now let's write the function that saves our local variables.

```
Future<void> saveData(String value) async {
  var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sharedPreferences.setString("yourVariable", value);
}
```

Now let's write your service function **onStart()**

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {

  // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  // For flutter prior to version 3.0.0
  // We have to register the plugin manually

  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setString("hello", "world");

  /// OPTIONAL when use custom notification
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
    
  // bring to foreground
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    // here we are passing method name and sendPort instance from ReceivePort as listener
    await Isolate.spawn(computationallyExpensiveTask, receivePort.sendPort);

    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
      if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        //It will listen for isolate function to finish
         receivePort.listen((sum) {
         flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
         888,
         'Title',
         'Description ${DateTime.now()}',
         const NotificationDetails(
         android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
         'my_foreground',
         'MY FOREGROUND SERVICE',
         icon: 'ic_bg_service_small',
         ongoing: true,
         ),
         ),
         );
         });

        var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await sharedPreferences.reload(); // Its important
        service.setForegroundNotificationInfo(
          title: "My App Service",
          content: "Updated at ${sharedPreferences.getString("yourVariable") ?? 'no data'}",
        );
      }
    }


    /// you can print
    //if (kDebugMode) {
    //}

    // test using external plugin
    final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String? device;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      device = androidInfo.model;
    }

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      device = iosInfo.model;
    }
    service.invoke(
      'update',
      {
        "current_date": '400',
        "device": device,
      },
    );
  });
}
```

Now let's call our service

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      readyForShared();
      ProjectBackgroundService().onStart();
    });
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).